# Loop getServerSideProps in nextjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

i am learning nextjs and i am trying to get the data from the db and show it in the index page, but when i run the getServerSideProps function it goes in a loop and keeps sending me the data in the terminal, how can I solve and show the data in the index page? thank you all

code index.js:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

export default function Home({utenti}) {
  return (
    <>
    <form method="POST" action='/api/sendInfo'>
      <label>Nome</label>
      <input type="text" name="nome"></input>

      <label>Cognome</label>
      <input type="text" name="cognome"></input>

      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email"></input>

      <button type="submit">Invia</button>
    </form>

    <div>
      <p>Select Utenti</p>
      
        <button type="submit" action = '/api/getInfo'  method="GET"> prendi utenti</button>
      
      
    </div>

    </>
  )
}


export async function getServerSideProps () {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const res = await fetch('http:127.0.0.1:3000/api/getInfo')
  const data =  await res.json()
  console.log ("Questi sono i data");
  console.log (data);
  // res.json(data)
  // Pass data to the page via props
  
  return { 
    utenti: {
       utenti: data 
     } 
  }
  
}
```

code http:127.0.0.1:3000/api/getInfo:

```
import connection from "../../db";

export default async(req, res) => {
  try{
    
    const query = 'SELECT * FROM Utenti'
    const result = await connection.query(
      query,
      
    );
  
    console.log(result);
    
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  
 
  res.redirect("/");  
}
```

Comment: Which part goes in a loop?  Client side?  Server side?

Comment: @James I think the getServerSide function keeps looping, but I can't figure out why

Comment: @DiegoM Can you give us more context about the problem?

Comment: @Amr I want to retrieve data from a db in postgres, and make them appear in the home, in this case the index.js file, to do this I thought of doing a getServerSideProps that fetches the api, but when I start the page the browser continues to turn and in the terminal I see that I continue to print the values of the db, not giving errors

Comment: Have you tried to fetch the data from the endpoint without SSR? with normal side effect hook?

Comment: @Amr  could it be that when I load the index page it starts the getServerSideProps function and since it redirects to the index it goes into a loop for this reason? if so how can i solve it?

Comment: @DiegoM `getServerSideProps` only runs on server-side and never runs on the browser.

Comment: @Amr no I haven't tried it yet, could you explain to me how it works?

Comment: @Amr I know, but I don't understand where the mistake is, he keeps doing the fetch

Comment: @DiegoM refer to this docs for more info about fetching data using side effect [hook](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useEffect#useeffect)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be redirecting in your API response, just return the JSON.

```
res.redirect("/");
```

should become:

```
res.status(200).json(results);
```

I think what is happening is the server keeps redirecting to `/` after each query, so there's a infinite loop of fetching the data.

Also, you should be returning

```
return {
  props: {
    utenti: data
  }
}
```

from `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: thanks now it works, but it gives me an error "TypeError: body used already for: http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/getInfo" what can it be?

Comment: I'd need more details. If the loop has stopped, I would close this question and post a new question with full context around the error